Definition of a local coordinate system as a mapping of region of $\mathbf{R}^n$ to the manifold (and not the inverse)
I am looking for differential geometry or analysis books that define a local coordinate system in $M$ as a mapping $U\to M$, where $U\subset\mathbf{R}^n$.
All that I've seen so far use the inverse mappings $V\to\mathbf{R}^n$, where $V\subset M$.
I prefer the "unusual" direction of the mapping because I do not want to insist that each point have unique coordinates -- think of the polar coordinate system, for example. (However, if the coordinates of a point do not uniquely determine that point, they do not deserve to be called its "coordinates" IMO.)
Update. I've found 2 so far:

James Munkres, Analysis on manifolds (1991).
Manfredo do Carmo and Francis Flaherty, Riemannian geometry (1992).


Does this answer your question? Why do we preference coordinate maps rather than their inverses in manifold theory?

@PaulFrost, thanks, somewhat it does. However, my question is mainly a reference request. I would prefer well-known or classical textbooks.

Spivak Calculus on Manifolds (in his DG volumes he flips them to the usual one).

What's the motivation behind this question? I typically start with the direction you want but then switch freely. Using the direction you prefer is good when you want to view the coordinates as input parameters and work with coordinate curves and vector fields. Using the opposite direction is useful when you want to work with the coordinates as functions of the manifold and use their differentials. Most often you want to work with coordinate vector fields and differentials simultanously, so you are using both directions simultaneously.

@Deane, I still need to give a definition. I would like to check the existing ones and be able to cite those that are similar to mine.

In this situation I don’t see the need to give specific citations.

@Deane, it depends. For example, it can spare other people posting this question here.

The maps are bijective and smooth so locally you do have unique coordinates. It doesn't matter which direction the arrows go. If two charts overlap, then by definition of a smooth atlas you have transition maps telling you how to go between the two charts.

I am asking for references. It is ok if the definition will require bijectivity, but it must be in the direction I indicated.

@Alexey Check Lee's Smooth Manifolds. Just take the inverse and it goes in the direction you want.

Sorry, this is not what I am asking for. I am asking for references where the maps in the definition of the coordinate charts/systems/patches go in the direction I want. When giving my definition, I would like to be able to cite other works where this is done similarly.
